# Format cell in Excel when value in a second row exists in a third row

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm trying to build a table in Excel to visualize some data from a SQL database, but I can't figure out the formula for this formatting.
Given a list (in columns A, B, and C below) of Stored Procedures that reference a given Table, I want to highlight the cell that corresponds to it. So, highlight a cell in a column when a cell in another column exists in a third column.

I've made an example below of how it should work:
[Link to image in case table formatting below is broken](https://i.stack.imgur.com/39puo.png)

Columns in Sheet 1 with source data:

| Column A | Column B | Column C |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Stored Procedure 1 | Stored Procedure 2 | Stored Procedure 1 |
| Stored Procedure 3 |  | Stored Procedure 2 |
|  |  | Stored Procedure 3 |

Columns in Sheet 2 with result table:

|  | Table A | Table B | Table C |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Stored Procedure 1 | Green |  | Green |
| Stored Procedure 2 |  | Green | Green |
| Stored Procedure 3 | Green |  | Green |

I figured the table in Sheet 1 with the source data was the best way to go about this, but I may be making it more difficult on myself? Is there an easier way to go about populating the result table?

Comment: Wow the example tables I made worked in the preview... I added a picture to see it instead.

Comment: Is this what you mean?: `=IF(ISNUMBER(MATCH($A2,'Sheet1'!A$1:A$3,0)),"GREEN","")` (for Table A if it starts in cell B2) if so, you could use the same for all cells.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

P.b already answered this very well, but I would like to add that you can use conditional formatting to do this.

If you create a custom format, you can choose the color green, and where it asks for a formula tell it

`=if(countif(sheet1!A:A,$A2)>0, true, false)`

And make sure the range it’s referring to is sheet2 cells b2:d4. You may have to double check the formula after, because I’ve seen times where changing the range the formatting applies to can mess with the cells in the function.

The function will check for any amount of cells in column a of sheet 1 that equal cell a2 of sheet 2. The formula will automatically drag across the cells, so column c (the second column) will be looking at column b in sheet 1.